# What should we do about badly formatted copy+pasted answers?

Tags: discussion

Answers from the Ethereum forum can be formatted quite poorly.

Example of one that's been cleaned up:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/344/revisions

I don't know if we'll be able to continuously format such answers.  Should such answers initially be downvoted, with a comment to clean them up?

Comment: I would also like to know this -

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we get questions from Reddit and the forums?](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-get-questions-from-reddit-and-the-forums)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think these should be allowed, or possibly just downvoted. Getting information from the forums is fine, but copy+pasting (especially without bothering to format) is bad. What often happens is that a series of posts are copied, which is not a good format for answers. Answers should get straight to the point rather than being a conversation.

Bad:

> Bobjoe520 said: Why do we do the thing with the stuff?
> JoeBob said: because it's better that way.
> Bobjoe530 said: but why is it better?
> BobExpert said: It's better because the foo of the bar and complicated explanation.

Good:

> From http://example.com/forumpost:
>
> > It's better because the foo of the bar and complicated explanation
> > — BobExpert

Better:

> The reason why the foo of the bar is because the bar of the foo is barry of the fooing *<complicated explanation>*
>
> More info here: http://example.com/forumpost

The key point I'm trying to make for "better" is to read and then re-word the post to answer the question in stackexchange style and to directly answer the question.

Comment: so Should such answers initially be downvoted, with a comment to clean them up?  or what to do to "disallow"?